# Identificar a chave da array do INPUT selecionado

Tags: javascript, jquery

Em um formulário HTML criei um campo `input[type='text']` com o atributo `name='input[][nome]'` e este campo é criados na DOM dinamicamente sob demanda do usuário, se o usuário criar 3 novos `inputs` o retorno do atributo `name` no `console.log` seria:

> input[0][nome]
>
> input[1][nome]
>
> input[2][nome]

Estou usando `Jquery` para facilitar o tempo de desenvolvimento e uma boa parte está em `Javascript`, fiz um depurador que exibe no `console.log` qual input está recebendo o foco e com o código abaixo é que me retorna o atributo `name`.

```
<input type='text' name='input[][nome]' class='add-item'/>

<script>
$('.add-item).on('click',function(){
    var nomeInput = $(this).attr('name');
    console.log(nomeInput); // retorna input[0][nome]
})
</script>
```

Dentro do código javascript gostaria de checar qual é o valor da chave atual, no caso acima é 0, mas é possível o código identificar isso sem mudança estrutural dessa função, apenas incrementando a mesma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que você está equivocado. O seu código não retorna o índice do input dentro dos colchetes, ele retorna o valor do atributo como ele está no HTML. Veja:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' name='input[][nome]' class='add-item'/>

<script>
$('.add-item').on('click',function(){
    var nomeInput = $(this).attr('name');
    console.log(nomeInput); // retorna input[][nome]
})
</script>
```

Agora, se você quer saber qual o índice do elemento dentro de uma coleção com a mesma `class`, você pode usar o método [.index()](https://api.jquery.com/index/):

```js
$('.add-item').on('click',function(){
    var indice = $(this).index();
    console.log("Índice do input:", indice, ". Deveria ser:", indice-1); // retorna o índice do elemento
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' name='input[][nome]' class='add-item'/>
<input type='text' name='input[][nome]' class='add-item'/>
<input type='text' name='input[][nome]' class='add-item'/>
```

**Não sei porque cargas d'água no snippet daqui o índice retorna um número a mais: 1, 2 e 3. Teste num arquivo .html no seu navegador que irá retornar corretamente: 0, 1 e 2.**

Neste [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/9mhskfve/) funciona corretamente.

Comment: resolveu geral, eu havia mapeado tudo para conseguir o índice, desconhecia .index(), hoje testei .map() e me retornou diferente, deveria reportar a divergência do snippet ao SO. Obrigado cordial.